# MSSQL varbinary insert

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with a varbinary(max) to contain images.

I sometimes scripts these as
insert into mytable(myvarbincol) values (0x123...).

This usually works.

However, I've seen two images fail in a rather strange way.

When inserting (or selecting the same number), I see something along the line of:

SELECT 0x12345

Result:
0x01234

It adds a 0 in front and cuts off the last "digit".

I mean I could understand if I'd somehow reached the max of a varbinary(max), and then got an error, but this is quite strange.

Anyone got an idea of why I see this? It ran on a MSSQL 2016, but I've tried it on a 2012 with the same result.

[Link to number giving strange results](https://www.dropbox.com/s/urbt08drqaqrhmh/faulty.sql?dl=0)

Comment: In 0x hexadecimal notation 2 characters represent each byte so the length must be a multiple of 2 - MSSQL is adding the 0 to the output to ensure this is the case, similarly it should not be outputting 0x01234. You need to show us something reproducible.

Comment: Certainly - the number was somewhat large. I'll edit my question

Comment: Added it as a link - too big to be in a stackoverflow question... :-O

Comment: Strange thing is, I can save things correct from my C# code...

Comment: Your input is 43677 chars long which is an odd number, meaning the binary value must begin with 08 instead of 8 as it currently does.  Another possibility is that there is 1 or more value missing from the end for some reason, or you are getting this data using a tool that has a limit on the results size/copy size it supports - to check this run `select datalength(varbinarycol)*2 from t`  and see if its 43678 which is the correct length value for your example.

Comment: Ah, I think that was it. I thought (because I'd been lucky with the other icon columns so far), that when you select a varbinary col, and it shows you 0x1234... etc, that you could copy it all out, even if not all was shown in the output table